# $(1+\frac{a_n}{n})^n \to e^x$ if $a_n \to x$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}{(1+x/n)^n}=e^x$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$. I want to prove that if $a_n\in \mathbb R$ is a sequence such that $a_n\to x$ then $(1+\frac{a_n}{n})^n \to e^x$.

I tried considering L.H rule, considering $f(x)\to x$ when $x\to \infty$ and then computing $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}(1+\frac{f(x)}{x})^x=\lim_{x\to \infty}{e^{x \ln (1+\frac{f(x)}{x})} }$

But it's difficult too. Please help me, maybe by definition or by Taylor Formula.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^n=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)\right)\sim_\infty\exp\left(n\frac{a_n}{n}\right)=\exp(a_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} e^x$$

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using logarithms? If the problem statement is true, then the log of the expression converge to $x$. Using Taylor series we have

$$n \log \left(1 + \frac{a_n}{n} \right) = n \left( \frac{a_n}{n} + O\left( \left(\frac{a_n}{n} \right)^2 \right) \right),$$
which clearly converges to $x$ if $a_n$ converges to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ such that if $n > N$, then $x - \epsilon < a_n < x + \epsilon$. So for such $n$ we have
$$(1 + {x - \epsilon \over n})^n < (1 + {a_n \over n})^n < (1 + {x + \epsilon \over n})^n$$
Now squeeze....